# React Native Function Call from Component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist, function-call

I am using Flatlist to show a list of Date. I have created a component `DateList` to view the list of item.

I have already called an API `apiFreelancerDate`. However, currently I am trying to call another function through the component (which I will later use it for second API call).

**Date screen:**

```
apiFreelancerDate = () => {
    let self = this;
    AsyncStorage.getItem('my_token').then((keyValue) => {
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: Constants.API_URL + 'user_m/confirmation_date/',
            params: {
                freelancer_id: self.props.navigation.state.params.fr_id,
            },
            responseType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'X-API-KEY': Constants.API_KEY,
                'Authorization': keyValue,
            },
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                self.setState({
                    dataSource: response.data.data,
                    isLoading: false,
                });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('Error Response: ', error.response);
            });
    }, (error) => {
        console.log('Error', error) //Display error
    });
}

 //test function call
testFunc = () => {
    console.log('test function called');
}
//test function call

viewFreelancerDate() {
    const { dataSource } = this.state;

    return (
        <View>
            {<FlatList
                data={dataSource}
                keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => index.toString()}
                renderItem={({ item }) => <DateList {...item} functionCall={this.testFunc}/>}
            />}
        </View>
    );
}
```

**DateList component:**

```
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={{ flex: 1 }}
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('masterFreelancerTime')}
            >
                <Text style={styles.textStartDate}>{this.props.date_start}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.activeBorder}
                onPress={() => {
                    this.props.functionCall;
                    const newStatus = !this.state.status;
                    this.setState({
                        status: newStatus,
                    });
                    console.log('status: ', this.state.status);
                    console.log('Date: ', this.props.date_start);
                }}
            >
                <Text style={styles.active_inactive}>{this.state.status ? "INACTIVE" : "ACTIVE"}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

I am very new to this so any help would be appreciated and I don't know if it's the right way to do it.

*My main purpose is that I want to add a function call that will call an API which will show the state `"INACTIVE" : "ACTIVE"` based on what's in the database. And upon pressing/tapping, the `"INACTIVE" : "ACTIVE"` will toggle and at the same time it'll update it's value in the database.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mostly on right track. Although you may want to keep few things in mind.

e.g.

```
<TouchableOpacity
    style={styles.activeBorder}
    onPress={() => {
        this.props.functionCall;
        const newStatus = !this.state.status;
        this.setState({
            status: newStatus,
        });
        console.log('status: ', this.state.status);
        console.log('Date: ', this.props.date_start);
    }}
>
```

This is an overoptimisic assignment to state.status before api call finishes. What if the api call fails, in that case, your status is not in-sync with database. You can update the state without waiting for API  to return the response, but you should update the state again in case API fails.

If you don't need optimistic state update, then you can do something like following:

Date screen:

```
 //test function call
testFunc = () => {
    console.log('test function called');
    const dataSource = makeAPiCallAndGetUpdatedApiSource();

    this.setState({ dataSource });
}
//test function call

viewFreelancerDate() {
    const { dataSource } = this.state;

    return (
        <View>
            {<FlatList
                data={dataSource}
                keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => index.toString()}
                renderItem={({ item }) => <DateList {...item} functionCall={this.testFunc}/>}
            />}
        </View>
    );
}
```

DateList component:

```
constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
        status: props.status
    };
}
...

componentDidUpdate() {
    this.setState({ status: this.props.status })
}

...

<TouchableOpacity
    style={styles.activeBorder}
    onPress={() => {
        this.props.functionCall();
    }}
>
```

This way, after the api call, state of date screen will be updated ... which in turn will update DateList component, which will update the state of component.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I forgot to mention that I will be making two api calls. The first call I have just edited and added on the Date Screen. And the second one would be the `testfunc()`. Could you confirm if the `dataSource` inside `testfunc` is the same as the rendered `dataSource` inside FlatList.

Comment: Yes, its the same (assuming each item in dataSource has `status` property ... which will be used to update the state of DateList component)